# Local Weather App FreeCodeCamp

Tags: javascript, json, api, openweathermap

Trying to figure out freecodecamp task, but it doesn't working even tracking youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZXg_fuyYnI&t=1385s . 
Please help, what is wrong in this code?

```
var API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$(function () {
    var loc;
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function (d) {
        console.log("assigning the data...")
        loc = d.loc.split(" , ");
        console.log(loc);
        $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + loc[0] + '&lon=' + loc[1] + '&APPID=' + API_KEY, function (wd) {
            console.log("got the data ,", wd);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Is there some error occurs?

Comment: Only thing I can assume for now< personnaly, that something wrong with string concat. Try smth like (I added " ' " after APIKEY)
`var requestStr = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+ loc[0] + '&lon=' + loc[1] +'&APPID=' + API_KEY + ';
$.getJSON( requestStr, function(wd){
 console.log("got the data ,", wd);
  })`

Answer (score 1):

Don't split on " , " (note the spaces) split just on ","

Not:

```
loc = d.loc.split(" , ");
```

But:

```
loc = d.loc.split(",");
```

From https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

> Syntax: string.split(separator, limit)
>
> separator: Optional. Specifies the character, or the regular
>   expression, to use for splitting the string. If omitted, the entire
>   string will be returned (an array with only one item)
>
> limit: Optional. An integer that specifies the number of splits, items
>   after the split limit will not be included in the array

By using a string with more than one character, I'm thinking that JavaScript is interpreting it as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, the problem is the presence of the spaces around the comma in the:

```
loc = d.loc.split(" , ");
```

which, instead, should be:

```
loc = d.loc.split(",");
```

**Reason**: the response from the [ipinfo.io IP lookup API](http://ipinfo.io/developers) contains a JSON object with the `loc` field being the coordinates comma separated with *no* spaces.

For example:

```
{
  "ip": "203.205.28.14",
  "hostname": "static.cmcti.vn",
  "city": "Ho Chi Minh City",
  "region": "Ho Chi Minh City",
  "country": "VN",
  "loc": "10.8142,106.6438",
  "org": "AS45903 CMC Telecom Infrastructure Company"
}
```

**Suggestion**: avoid to expose your *Open Weather Map private Key* (`appid`) also when you publish the finished freeCodeCamp challenge (I used *CodePen* and I did not like the idea of my private key being exposed, so I wrote [Open Weather Map Proxy](https://github.com/lorepirri/open-weather-map-proxy) a JS script which anybody can *copy&paste* into a personal new *Google Scripts App* and use it as pass through service).